# Calibre in Debian 7.3 KDE doesn't have cover browser?

Tags: debian, kde, 32bit, calibre

Can someone please help me to activate the **cover browser** of Calibre in Debian 7.3 KDE desktop (32 bit architecture)? I've tried toggling the arrow button in the bottom-right corner but unlike the other buttons, it yields nothing, not even a tool-tip when I hover over it. I've tried also clicking `Preferences > Look&feel > Cover Browser tab` but there's nothing usable there. Please see the pictures below.

[image: missing cover browser]

[image]

**NOTE:** I'm using version 0.8.51.

Comment: What version of Calibre are you using? I have 1.7 and it's working fine. It also might be the case that your graphics card isn't up to flipping through the images.

Comment: As you can see from the status bar of Calibre in the pictures I posted, mine is version 0.8.51. How do I upgrade it to 1.7? I downloaded it from Synaptick Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Calibre you're using is quit old (0.8.51), I would attempt to update it to a newer version. I'm using Calibre 1.7 on Fedora 19 and the cover browser functionality works fine there.

To update Calibre on Debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get update calibre
```

Also you can try installing the binary builds of Calibre that are made available from the Calibre project's website. They're available here:

- http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

You also might be able to get newer builds from Jessie, I noticed that this release of Debian has Calibre 1.14.

- http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=calibre

Comment: updating Calibre through Konsole didn't work. From the Debian pkges, it seems Wheezy is built this way. Also,the official download page of Calibre states: _WARNING: calibre is a highly complex piece of software with lots of very finicky dependencies. If you install from source, you are on your own. Please do not open bug reports or expect any form of support. You have been warned._ I would therefore, leave just like it is. As long as I can read the files, I'm fine. I thought I had to enable something to get the cover browser, but it's a _finesse_, a luxury that I can do without.

Comment: @WobbyWindows - Yup saw that. Your call. If you can't get an update through other means, that or upgrading your system are your only 2 other options. I'd explore getting the package from Jessie and seeing it you can't build it for Wheezy.

Comment: @WobbyWindows - I would probably go with your option, and do nothing and live w/o the feature until you absolutely have to have it.